# The Logic Problems of Black Holes

Tags: black-holes

As I always preference my questions, I am not a scientist or student.  I am an engineer who loves physics.

It is my understanding that, there are 2 competing thoughts behind what a black hole is.

Standard Description – Is that a stellar core collapses under its own weight when it begins to fuse iron.  It shrinks to a point of infinite density and an event horizon is formed.  Time splits from space just below the event horizon.  Matter falling into the event horizon will eventually meet the singularity.

The second description is like the first, except that matter never falls below the event horizon and piles up on it.  (This is due to time ending at the event horizon).  The black hole and event horizon expands because of this shell of material on it.

Both descriptions are illogical.  They might make sense from a mathematics point of view, but they have problems from a purely logical point of view.

Standard Description

1. Density - Let’s say we have a BH at 10 solar masses.  If I push another solar mass of material into the event horizon, how can something that was infinitely dense, become even more infinitely dense?
2. Size – How can matter collapse to a singularity… (Now I understand that it is a mathematical singularity which means we have pushed physics to its breaking point…)

Logically you cannot be infinitely dense, and infinitely small.  You can be one of the other, but not both.

If you are infinitely dense, any matter falling onto you would have to pile up around the singularity as it cannot be squeezed any further.

If you are infinitely small (let’s say a Planck Length in size), then you cannot be infinitely dense, as new material must be squeezed into this Planck Length as well.

3. Energy – I would expect that as the quarks are destroyed in the collapse, they would give off a TREMENDOUS amount of energy.  Where does this go?  Why does it not push back against gravity blowing the stellar core apart?

(I do not think there is anything that keeps the “singularity” from being pure energy is there?)

4. If you have an infinitely dense, infinitely small singularity, how does the event horizon grow?

Second Description

1. If time ceases, just at the event horizon and all matter deposited on the event horizon forms shells around it why is it not reflective?  It would no longer be a black body as matter on the top of the shell would be further away than the event horizon and the escape velocity would be less than the speed of light.
   To me this is the easiest to get around.  Time does indeed stop just “BELOW” the event horizon.  Matter does not collapse into a singularity and therefore is not infinitely dense.  As matter is drawn into the event horizon, it piles up on the core and enlarges the event horizon.  (Think of a glass that as you add water, keeps expanding.)  However, I don’t think this is mathematically supported.

I am sure there other paradox’s surrounding black holes.  These are the ones that have made me curious.

Comment: The actuall paradoxes still left in our understanding of a black hole are much more subtle then any of the ones you have laid out. I would say the most striking one is the Black hole information paradox (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox) 

as for the rest of your paradoxes, you say a lot of things are impossible because they violate your intuition (i.e. Logically you cannot be infinitely dense, and infinitely small.) How sure are you that you have interacted (calculated) with similar enviroments to build those intuitions?

Comment: As I said, I am not a scientist, but an engineer.  But if your are infinitely dense, and small, how do you get denser and stay the same size?

Comment: I understand that understand that information is usually preserved in normal spacetime, but as time space time is destroyed in a BH, why does it HAVE to be preserved here?  A system's wavefunction should logically be destroyed in a BH.. (I may have not said that correctly.  If I didn't I apologize.)

Comment: Rick, can you please break this up to ask just one question at a time?

Comment: Re, "...as the quarks are destroyed in the collapse..." There is no theory that allows quarks to be "destroyed." Meanwhile, GR forbids us from ever seeing what _actually_ happens to matter under the extreme conditions that it predicts near the singularity. There's no paradox in that: It's just a sign that there may yet be new ideas and new phenomena out there, waiting to be discovered by physicists.

Comment: "I always preference my questions". Do you mean *"preface"*?

Comment: You are discussing the classical Newtonian physics case. For large energies and masses this has to be superceded . General relativity has  given a mathematical framework that can describe our observations in astrophysics including black holes. There exist modified newtonian theories (MOND in wikipedia) which try to  do the same, unsuccessfully up to now.

Answer (score 3):

> Both descriptions are illogical

I will focus my comments on the first description. The second description is only valid in one set of coordinates, so it is more a commentary on those coordinates than it is on the physics.

Also, since your comments are regarding the logic I will address the mathematical logic of the GR model. We expect that this model does not represent the actual physics near the singularity, but as a model it is logical, meaning that it is self-consistent.

> how can something that was infinitely dense, become even more infinitely dense?

It is important to understand that the singularity is not part of the spacetime manifold. So you cannot speak of mass at the singularity. However, you can speak of mass infinitesimally close to the singularity. This is easiest to do with the hyperrreals instead of just the real numbers. But equivalent statements can be made with the reals.

In that context, if $V=\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal volume and $m$ is a finite mass then $m/\epsilon$ is an infinite density. By the normal operations on hyperreals any finite number divided by any infinitesimal number is infinite. Similarly, if $M$ is another finite mass with $m<M$ then $M/\epsilon$ is also an infinite density with $m/\epsilon < M/\epsilon$.

This is perfectly logical that one infinite number may be larger than another infinite number. Infinite numbers have the property that any infinite number is larger than any finite number, but a number may be larger than any finite number and yet smaller than a specified infinite number. It is illogical to assume that all infinite numbers must be equal.

> If you are infinitely dense, any matter falling onto you would have to pile up around the singularity as it cannot be squeezed any further.

Your statement here is a material model. Basically, you are suggesting that there is some maximum compression. While that might well be a physically correct model, it does not mean that alternative models are illogical. There is no self contradiction in a model where increased force leads to increased compression without limit. The current model basically says that any force greater than the neutron degeneracy pressure leads to arbitrarily high compression.

> Why does [quark energy] not push back against gravity blowing the stellar core apart?

This is the source of the neutron degeneracy pressure. It does push back as much as it can, but the degeneracy pressure is not infinite. It simply is not strong enough to oppose collapse.

> If you have an infinitely dense, infinitely small singularity, how does the event horizon grow?

The singularity is in the future of the horizon, so the singularity does not cause the horizon. The horizon forms prior to the formation of the singularity. The horizon forms from the collapsing matter before the singularity forms, and it grows as more matter crosses it, regardless of even whether or not there is a singularity.

Comment: Also, pressure doesn't purely oppose gravity. In GR, pressure (and momentum flux) contribute to the stress-energy-momentum tensor. So increased pressure increases the gravity in a positive feedback loop.

Comment: Yes, good point. It is a little tricky in a spherically symmetric spacetime because of Birkhoff’s theorem. The pressure does contribute locally, but outside it is just the same as an equivalent amount of energy.

Comment: True, but I was focusing on Rick's *"Why does it not push back against gravity blowing the stellar core apart?"* It seems that pressure ought to oppose the stellar core collapse, it's a bit unintuitive that the pressure also contributes to the collapse.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this "The horizon forms prior to the formation of the singularity."?

Comment: The singularity is literally the end of time. It literally comes after everything else. So it cannot cause anything since causes always come before effects.